# Can't connect to Github's website in Chrome but it works when I use Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, github, insecure-connection

https://i.imgur.com/qKyu744.jpg

This started happening just a few days ago. I can access the site on the same computer in Firefox. Not sure why it is telling me that the site is insecure, but that must be related. I tried ipconfig /flushdns, deleting my cookies, and disabling my firewall but none of those fixed it. Can't find any solutions online either so far. Using the latest Chrome update and Windows 10. Please help!

Edit: Solved my issue by installing this Windows update:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4284835

Comment: Backup your whole information (passwords, bookmarks etc.) then reinstall ?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you might have deleted trusted certificates from chrome trust store (github CA SSL certificate  is issued by `DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA` ), where as in for other browsers the trust store must be a different location in your case.

To check above listed certificate present in Chrome trusted store or not, do the following

Open Chrome then Go to `Settings => Manage Certificates` - Click on it, when Certificates pop-up shows then check at' **Trusted Root Certificates Authorities**, if desired certificate is not present then import it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I see two there with the exact same name, though the friendly name and the certificate intended purposes are different. https://i.imgur.com/WqwlDYz.jpg                                 
and https://i.imgur.com/DG4EM4T.jpg

Comment: Ok, I look at my other system which connects through VPN, so this time the github CA certificates refers to other provider than mentioned above, what you can do it is, just goto github.com then download certificate for importing to Chrome. Please take a note to download CA certificate whoever provider it shows in your case.

Comment: While I was waiting for your reply I tried to think of any other standard procedure stuff I could try. I noticed I had a Windows update pending so I installed and restarted, and that seems to have fixed it! I just found another post that described the same issue and solution as well. Not sure why a Windows update would fix the inability to access a specific website on Chrome though, since that would imply a previous Windows update caused it. I had no idea Windows updates could do that.  https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/8qqsue/err_connection_reset_trying_to_access_githubcom/e0lc9mw/

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, this is what worked for me:

1. Open up the start menu and search for and open "Internet Options".
2. Go to the "Connections" tab.
3. Click on "LAN settings".
4. Untick all the checkboxes (there are 3).
5. Click OK twice and then access https://github.com/ via Google Chrome.

The reason why it works on Firefox is because it has its own proxy settings. Google Chrome takes the proxy settings of the computer.

Answer (score 1):

If you enter the website URL with www, it will work in chrome.
To avoid this you need to add another CNAME without www.

Answer (score 1):

I am using MacOS and I had similar issue of accessing GitLab with Chrome, but no issue with Safari.

What helps me finally is: Setting -> Privacy and Security, and turn off "Use Secure DNS".

Answer (score -1):

If CORS extension has been downloaded and enabled in the Chrome browser then disable the CORS(Allow-control-Allow-origin) extension. It will work..!